# Qlikview set analysis with multiple conditions

Tags: qlikview

I have the following set analysis with one condition.

=sum({1} bank_shr_bal)/1000000

I need to create a second condition that filters the months the data collects from. The date column needs to be greater than a variable created called "minusYear" and the dimension I'm comparing it to is called MonthEnd. I'm really not sure how to do a greater than with Qlikview set analysis.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<>` set modifier syntax with your `MonthEnd` field. It would look like this:

```
=sum({1<MonthEnd=">$(minusYear)">}bank_shr_bal)/1000000
```

The set you are are looking at is the entire universe because you used the `1` as your set identifier. Then the modifier `<MonthEnd=">$(minusYear)">` restricts the the set to only those values meeting the condition defined for MonthEnd. The `"` is used for expressions in QV so we can write the expression `> $(minusYear)` between the quotes and the expression will get resolved.